# Como utilizar o FreeTDS com MAMP no Mac OS?

Tags: php, sql-server, freetds, mamp, osx

Preciso utilizar os métodos **mssql_** do **PHP** e sempre fiz isso utilizando o **FreeTDS** no Apache nativo do **MAC OS**.

O que acontece é que logo após fazer a atualização para o **OS X 10.9** (Mavericks) passei a utilizar o pacote MAMP e não mais o Apache nativo por questões pessoais e pela facilidade na personalização do Apache/PHP.

Sei que preciso ativar a extensão no **php.ini** (no meu caso está em `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/conf/php.ini`) porém não tenho certeza se preciso compilar o PHP novamente.

Alguém teria ideia da melhor forma a proceder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Instalando o Free TDS

- Crie o diretório `/usr/local/freetds`
- Faça download do freetds: ftp://ftp.freetds.org/pub/freetds/current/freetds-current.tgz
- Abra uma janela de terminal e descompactar o arquivo que acabou de baixar
- No terminalvá até a pasta criada após descompactar

  ```
  cd ~/Downloads/freetds-current
  ```
- Execute o seguinte comando em seguida

  ```
  ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/freetds --sysconfdir=/usr/local/freetds/conf/freetds --disable-libiconv --disable-odbc
  ```
- Após concluir digite "make" e pressione enter
- Digite `sudo make install` e enter novamente
- Digite sua senha e espere concluir.

## Compilando o PHP para obter o mssql.so

- Faça download da versão que está utilizando (http://php.net/downloads.php)
- No terminal entre no diretório descompactado do php que acabou de baixar.
- Digite `./configure` e pressione enter.
- Depois "make" e enter
- Vá até a pasta da extensão do mssql

  ```
  cd ~/Downloads/php-<versão>/ext/mssql
  ```
- Digite `phpize` e enter
- Digite o comando abaixo após isso

  ```
  ./configure --with-mssql=/usr/local/freetds
  ```
- Abra um Editor de texto e edite o arquivo:

  ```
  ~/Downloads/php-<versão>/ext/mssql/php_mssql.c
  ```

Altere a linha 181 trocando PHP_FE_END para {NULL, NULL, NULL}

```
// Antes
PHP_FE(mssql_guid_string, arginfo_mssql_guid_string)
    PHP_FE_END
};

// Depois
PHP_FE(mssql_guid_string, arginfo_mssql_guid_string)
    {NULL, NULL, NULL}
};
```

- Volte para o terminal - verifique se ainda está na pasta `~/Downloads/php-<versao>/ext/mssql`
- Digite `make` e enter
- Abra o `finder` e vá até a pasta do modulo do mssql (`~/Downloads/php-<versão>/ext/mssql/modules/`)
- Copie `mssql.so` para a pasta de extensão do MAMP. Deve ser algo como `Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php-<versão>/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/`
- Edite o seu `php.ini` `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php-<versão>/conf/php.ini`
- Procure por `extension=`
- Cole `extension=mssql.so` logo abaixo as outras linhas de extensões e reinicie o MAMP